# ¿Qué fue antes, el "currusco" o el "cuscurro"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa, historia, sustantivos

En una conversación en *[La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia)* ha quedado patente que media España dice *[currusco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BkPMgIE)* y la otra media dice *[cuscurro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BmBFJzk)* para referirse a lo mismo:

> 1. m. Parte del pan más tostada que corresponde a los extremos o al borde.

En el DLE, la palabra *currusco* redirige a *cuscurro*, lo que podría hacer pensar que esta última es anterior (o a lo mejor la más usada). Sin embargo, tanto *currusco* como *cuscurro* dice que provienen de *[corrusco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B0vZF0w)*, que dice que es de origen onomatopéyico, aunque su significado redirige de nuevo a *cuscurro*.

Por tanto parece que inicialmente fue *corrusco*, pero de entre las variantes, ¿qué fue antes? ¿El *currusco* o el *cuscurro*?

Comment: En el CORDE la primera coincidencia de *cuscurro* es de 1880 mientras que de *currusco* es de 1905. Ambas palabras devuelven muy pocos resultados como para poder afirmar nada y son palabras más usadas en el habla que en la literatura.

Answer (score 4):

En *Google n-grams* (que parece tener un corpus más amplio que el de *CORDE*), las ocurrencias primeras registradas de cada palabra son:

***Currusco / churrusco*** (1852)

- [Compendio del diccionario nacional de la lengua española, Volume 1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2O1FAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA684&dq=%22currusco%22), Ramon Joaquin Dominguez

  > CHURRUSCO, m. Pedazo de pan socarrado. || Currusco.

***Cuscurro*** (1847)

- [Diccionario de la lengua castellana](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=h9DeaVxq5S4C&pg=PA289&dq=%22cuscurro%22), D. y M.

  > Cuscurro, *m*, canterito de pan.

***Corrusco*** (1805)

- [Ensayo histórico-crítico sobre el orígen y progresos de las lengua: señaladamente del romance Castellano](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DcEwAQAAMAAJ&q=%22corrusco%22), Francisco Martínez Marina

  > CORRUSCO, قرص *coruso*, crustulum panis.

<s>Pero, aquí hay un corrusco de 1644 con una definición diferente:</s>

- <s>[Tesoro de las tres lenguas, española, francesa y italiana](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yyY-AAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PA138&dq=%22corrusco%22), Girolamo Vittori</s>

  > <s>Corruſco, add.ſplendente, *resplendiſſant*, reſplandeciente.</s>

**Edit:** [Esta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corrusco#Italian) es un homónimo/homógrafo italiano.

Comparación de la frecuencia de las tres palabras en [*Google n-grams*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cuscurro%2Ccurrusco%2Ccorrusco&year_start=1780&year_end=2000&corpus=21).

Comment: +1 Linda respuesta. Las dos opciones son nuevas para mí (angloparlante que vivo en Chile) pero voy a adoptar una de ellas. ¡Ya se me hizo agua la boca pensando en el currusco calentito con mantequilla!